# How can i send data over HttpsUrlConnection using the PUT Method in JAVA?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, https

I have made the secure connection using the HttpsURLConnection. I can carry out the get and post methods successfully, but when I am trying to use same POST method code with the PUT method, I am getting the error code 400. I found on google that StringEntity is used for sending data for HttpURLConnection but it is not supported with HttpsURLConnection.
Can someone please guide me how can I perform the PUT method on HTTPS.
There is really very less support available on google regarding HTTPS. Is there any blog which may help on this?

Below is my code:

```
public void methodPut(JSONObject JsonObj) throws Exception
{
    //making the connection object and passing it through the ssl certificate using the simple x509trustmanager class
    String httpsURL = <here goes my HTTPS URL>;
    URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
    SSLContext ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
    ssl.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new SimpleX509TrustManager()}, null);
    SSLSocketFactory factory = ssl.getSocketFactory();
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
    con.setSSLSocketFactory(factory);

    //preparing the connection for PUT
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
    con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    con.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json"); 
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("X-API-Version", "120");
    con.setUseCaches( false );


    //adding the json data as the parameter

    OutputStreamWriter wr= new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(JsonObj.toString());  //JsonObj contains all the data that needs to be modified
    wr.flush();

    //getting the information from the server

     InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
     InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

     //output the information        

     String inputLine;
     while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
     {
         System.out.println(inputLine);
     }
     in.close();

}
```

This way it works for POST method, but not for PUT. I tried several other things but couldn't do it.Please Help.

Below is my error log:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:<my HTTPS URL>
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at rest.HttpsClient.methodPut(HttpsClient.java:261)
at rest.GetOneViewDetails.main(GetOneViewDetails.java:97)
```

Error is coming on the line:

```
   InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
```

Comment: `HTTP 400` means that the parameters `wr.write(JsonObj.toString());` you have sent are incorrect

Comment: The issue is with the server, it is returning HTTP status `400 Bad Request`. Are you sure the server accepts PUT requests?

Comment: yes, accessing the server with the same data with advanced rest client of chrome gives the desired result. that means server accepts the put request and also the data is correct.
are you sure the function I am using here are correct? isn't there anything else i need to add or replace for PUT request?

Comment: I am really sorry, i figured out that i forgot to put the sessionkey which was required in my code. i added it by
          con.setRequestProperty("Auth", sessionKey);
and now its working fine.
Thanks for your help.
I hope this question may help someone to find the code for PUT request in HTTPS as i struggled a lot for the same.